# Packages.config and binding redirects

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

We're having some build issues due to package issues, but one of our devs got a green build by downgrading a package in the project's `packages.config`:

```
<package id="Microsoft.Data.Edm" version="5.6.2" targetFramework="net451" />
```

This was also added to the project's config file:

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Data.Edm" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.6.4.0" newVersion="5.6.4.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

If we have amended the version in the packages.config to 5.6.2, but still point to 5.6.4 in our binding redirect, what version of the `Microsoft.Data.Edm` assembly is the project going to use?

Comment: Good question. Did you ever get an answer to this question?